# Achieve consistent symbol height independently from subscript and superscript

Tags: math-mode, boxes, subscripts, superscripts

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \fbox{\(+\)}, \fbox{{\(+_L\)}}, \fbox{{\(+^R\)}}, \fbox{{\(+^R_L\)}}
\end{document}
```

it produces:

[image]

As you can see, the surrounding box greatly changes in vertical size, and it produces a rather uncanny effect on one of my documents.

*Is there any way to make all those boxes the same height (vertical size)?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a \strut so most single line terms will fit:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \fbox{\strut\(+\)}, \fbox{\strut\(+_L\)}, \fbox{\strut\(+^R\)}, \fbox{\strut\(+^R_L\)}
\end{document}
```